# Creating an all in one requests function for shorter easier code in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm Trying to create an all in one function that handles all my API requests and cuts down on lots of repeated code especially with all of the error handling for different error codes.

I am using a few files different files to achieve this a.py that connects to "api a" and b.py that connect to "api b" and api.py that contains the function
a.py and b.py both start with

```
from api import *
```

and use

```
login_response = post_api_call(api_url_base + login_url, None , login_data).json()
```

or similar

api.py contains the below, but will be fleshed out with more error handling with retries etc which is what I don't want to be repeating.

```
import requests
import logging

def post_api_call (url, headers, data):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print ("Http Error:",errh)
        logging.warning("Http Error:" + errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
        logging.warning ("Error Connecting:" + errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
        logging.warning ("Timeout Error:" + errt)
    # only use above if want to retry certain errors, below should catch all of above if needed.
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
        logging.warning ("OOps: Something Else" + err)
    # retry certain errors...
    return response
```

The above works and isn't an issue.

The issue I'm having is I'm trying to not have different functions for post/get/push etc. how can I pass this through as a variable?
The other issue I am having is some APIs need the data passed as "data=data" others only work when I specify "JSON=data". Others need headers while some don't, but if I pass headers = None as a variable i get 405 Errors. The only other way round it that I can think of is long nested if statements which is nearly as bad as the repeating code.

Am I trying to over simplify this? Is there a better way?

The scripts have a number of API calls (minimum of 5) to a number of different APIs (currently 3 but expecting this to grow) it will then combine all the received data, compare it to the database and the run any updates against the necessary APIs.

Comment: Maybe a context manager?

Comment: Or more parameters to your function? `post_api_call(method, url, ...)`? And perhaps create a class that has `self.POST(self, url)` etc, and the function call just redirects to the appropriate function belonging to the particular request you want to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Imports:**

```
from requests import Request, Session
```

**Method:**

```
def api_request(*args, **kwargs):
    if "session" in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs["session"], Session):
        local_session = kwargs["session"]
        del kwargs["session"]
    else:
        local_session = Session()

    req = Request(*args, **kwargs)
    prepared_req = local_session.prepare_request(req)

    try:
        response = local_session.send(prepared_req)
    except:
        # error handling
        pass

    return response
```

**Usage:**

```
sess = Session()
headers = {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
    "User-Agent": "test-app"
}

result = api_request("GET", "http://www.google.com", session=sess, headers=headers)

print(result.text)
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm sure I would not have found *args, **kwargs with searching!
But I cant get past `if "session" in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs["session"], Session):
NameError: name 'Session' is not defined` if sess is past in the kwargs, if I remove it then  `local_session = Session()
NameError: name 'Session' is not defined` with your code

Comment: @Ian, have you imported requests like I wrote in post?

Comment: Must have been a copy paste fumble or indent issue, seems to be working

Comment: @Ian, if my answer helped you to solve your problem, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.